# Adicionar exceção no Cell.Delete

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estava usando essa Sub ClearContents para limpar todo o conteúdo que possuía nas sheets, preciso adicionar uma exceção que é a célula G1 e encontrei essa outra Sub, porém não sei como misturar as duas

```
Sub ClearContents()

 Application.Calculation = xlManual
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Sheets("01-Janeiro").Cells.Delete
  Sheets("02-Fevereiro").Cells.Delete
  Sheets("03-Março").Cells.Delete
  Sheets("04-Abril").Cells.Delete
  Sheets("05-Maio").Cells.Delete
  Sheets("06-Junho").Cells.Delete
  Sheets("07-Julho").Cells.Delete
  Sheets("08-agosto").Cells.Delete
  Sheets("09-Setembro").Cells.Delete
  Sheets("10-Outubro").Cells.Delete
  Sheets("11-Novembro").Cells.Delete
  Sheets("12-Dezembro").Cells.Delete

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Sub ClearAllExceptSelection()
'updateby Extendoffice 20151113
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xAddress As String
    Dim xUpdate As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    xAddress = Application.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the ranges want to keep", "Kutools for Excel", xAddress, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Intersect(xCell, xRg) Is Nothing Then
            xCell.Clear
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate
End Sub
```

Preciso apagar tudo que estiver na sheet e manter o G1 intacto e se souber também como aplicar isso nessa função me ajudaria

```
Public Function SheetClear(Name As String)
Dim s As Worksheet, t As String
Dim i As Long, k As Long
k = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count

For i = k To 1 Step -1
    t = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
    If t = Name Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Cells.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next i
```

End Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugestão: Preserve o conteúdo da célula G1 numa variável, limpe tudo e depois volte o valor para a célula.

```
Public Function SheetClear(Name As String)
Dim s As Worksheet, t As String
Dim i As Long, k As Long

Dim CelulaG1 As String 'Ou double, ou integer, depende do tipo de dado que está em G1

    k = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    For i = k To 1 Step -1
        t = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
        If t = Name Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                CelulaG1 = Sheets(i).Range("G1").Value
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Cells.Delete
                Sheets(i).Range("G1").Value = CelulaG1
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```